# 'ChunkLoadError' occurs only to some users... why?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sentry, code-splitting, webpack-splitchunks

On a react + webpack project, after implementing code splitting, I started to see **chunk load errors on the sentry**. **However, this is only happening to a few users.** I have never encountered chunk load errors on the site, nor has any of my teammates. We can't pinpoint exactly who experiences the chunk load error, (as it's just reported on the sentry). We only know that chunk load error occurs to a few users.

We host all our JS, CSS files on CDN, and we keep a separate folder for each deployment version and in the folder keep all the build files except index.html. So the old chunk files still remain in the folder.

How can I go about resolving this issue? I would love to get some pointers to why this error might be happening to only certain users.

Do certain browsers have limits to how many chunks can be downloaded? We do apply `splitChunks: { chunks: 'all' }`, so I wonder whether this is leading to some delays in loading for those users...?